# How can i check to see if my WordPress code is correct?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to enqueue a script into my WordPress theme, but i have no way to tell if it is correct. The script isn't working, so what am i doing wrong?

```
function buns_bootstrap_js(){

    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapjs', get_stylesheet_directory() . 'js/bootstrap.min.js',    array('jquery'),'3.2.0');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'buns_bootstrap_js');
```

Comment: Right click your website, click "view source code" (or similar) and check if the file is there. and if the path is correct.

Comment: Thanks @hildende, everything is correct but the script is not showing in the "source".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to learn how to use the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see the Javascript loading on your site and any script errors.

And use Debug in WordPress https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress to check for PHP errors that may exist in your use of `wp_enqueue_script`.

Check the docs, if needed, for `wp_enqueue_script` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Thanks, it was a misspell error with the parameter of add_action(). I typed wp_enqueue_script instead of wp_enqueue_scripts.